# To pass parameters in Prefix or Post notation

Tags: programming

For the table

```
tab = {{"", "Ville A", "Ville B"}, {"Modalité", "Nombre de Personnes",
 "Nombre de Personnes"}, {"Emplacement", 40, 
30}, {"Surface Terrain", 35, 30}, {"Surface maison", 25, 
30}, {"Qualité du bati", 20, 20}, {"Total", 120, 120}};

tab // Grid
```

set the `tab` data in a grid. But I want it framed. If I expand the command `Grid[]` with `Frame -> True`, I obtain what I want. But  can I obtain the same with a post- or a prefix notation?

Comment: `tab // Grid // Framed`

Comment: you can do like `// Grid[#,Frame -> True]&`

Comment: Thanks  george2079. You show that, in that case, there is not gain to adopt a pre or postfix notation.